# How to bypass NullPointerException in a smart way

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm looking for a 'smart' way to not meet the NullPointerException while returning an object in a method.
So, for instance, the main class looks like this:

```
public class MyCar{
  String colour; 
  int price;
  public MyCar(String colour, int price){
     this.colour = colour;
     this.price = price;
  }
  
  public void getValue(){
      return this.value;
  }
}
```

Then I've got a class that stores information about a manufacturer and list of cars he has:

```
public class Manufacturer{
    
    ArrayList<MyCar> cars = new ArrayList<MyCar>();
    String make;
    
    public Manufacturer(String make, ReportOnCar report){
        String.make = make;
        report.addManufacturer(this);
    }
    
    public MyCar highestValue(){
        if(this.cars.isEmpty()){
            // 1. what to return here as I want to have something nice like just a print out that there are no cars in this make, so you need to add cars first. Because as it prevents to throw null exception the only thing I can think of doing is writing 'return null'
        }else{
            MyCar temp = this.MyCar.get(0);
            for(int i = 1; i < this.cars.size(); i++){
                if(this.cars.get(i).getValue > temp.getValue()){
                    temp = this.cars.get(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also it has a method to find the most expensive car among this manufacturers car.
Then I have a class which holds exactly all the manufacturers. It's like a class which puts all the information together.

```
public class ReportOnMan{
    private ArrayList<Manufacturer> allMans = new ArrayList<Manufacturer>;
    
    public void addManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer){
        this.allMans.add(manufacturer)
    }
    // method to find most expensive car amongs all manufacturers
    public mostExpensive(){
        MyCar tempCar = null; // here my main problem begins
        double tempHighest = 0;
        for(Manufacturer man : this.allMans){
            if(man.highestValue().getValue() > tempHighest){
                tempCar = man.highestValue();
                tempHighest = dist.highestValue().getValue();
            }
        }
        return tempCar;
    }
}
```

So as you see here is a function that returns the most expensive car of all manufacturers. My question is, how should I catch the NullPointerException in this situation. As for example, what if the array 'cars' in Manufacturer is empty and then it will be returning me an empty Object in the mostExpensive() method and it will throw NullPointerException. So my question is how can I bypass it. What's the best option for it.
Because at the moment my only idea is before calling method mostExpensive() check first whether at least one Manufacturer has a car but I think there is another way around, which I cannot think of.

Comment: Returning null is the correct pattern when searching for a match in a list that contains no matches. You should correctly respond to the possibility of null in the code that calls this method.

Comment: This `public void getValue() { return this.value; }` won't compile. --- In general, if a method may return a `null`, one can opt to let it return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) instead.

Comment: you also could create special static instance and return it instead: ```public static MyCar NULL_CAR = new MyCar(); ```  not the best solution here probably

Comment: but the thing is that whenever list is empty yet, it raises the exception. So what you say is it is a normal thing so before I start this function I should check whether manufacturers list is not empty and if there are cars in each manufacturer, if there isn't I should return null?

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to realize is to think about *what does null actually mean?*

It can be used to mean various things. Baked right into the language is 'the variable is not yet set to anything' - that's what happens when you write:

```
class Foo {
    String bar;
}
```

here, `bar` will be a `null` reference.

It also tends to mean 'irrelevant', 'unknown', or 'not found'. For example:

```
Map<String, String> someMap = ....;
String v = someMap.get("Hello");
```

here, `v` will be `null` if `"Hello"` is not a key in this map, i.e., `null` is returned to indicate "not found".

These values all have something in common: They *come with no semantic baggage*. In particular, `null` **does not, and should never** mean *empty*. For example, if you ever write:

```
if (x == null || x.isEmpty())
```

you're doing it wrong. If you need an empty object, then - use it. Return `""`, or `List.of()`, or whatever goes for 'empty object'. Don't return null for this stuff. You want the language to be working for you, not against you. When you try to ask a non-existent result about a property, the correct response is **not** to presume some default value. it is **to crash**. If you look up some string in a map and then ask for that string's length, the answer in case the string you looked for is not found is **not** 0. You don't know the right answer; the code is clearly written with the assumption a result would always be found, and the only correct move for code in the face of assumptions that aren't met, is to throw an exception, right on the line where the assumption fails.

This is exactly what you get, if you let `null` function as 'undefined', 'unset', 'irrelevant', 'not found', 'not applicable', etcetera. It's *not* what you get when you use `null` as a standin for a well defined state (such as an empty string, no elements in a collection or array, etcetera).

Once you think about this, let's go back to your code: what does 'give me the most expensive car amongst all of these zero manufacturers' even mean?

I don't think it makes sense to make any assumptions about the calling code and what they think should happen in such a case.

4 strategies:

- Dummy objects. Make a car instance that represents 'no car', and return that. This is usually a bad idea because it tends to lead to code that silently does nothing when assumptions fail. This is bad: You'll spend hours finding the bug, and it's hard to test for. Exceptions are nice: They tell you where to look, and they are hard to miss. NPE (NullPointerException) is vastly superior to 'incorrectly do nothing, silently'. It can make sense though - more usually for objects with a clear 'blank' variant, such as empty arrays, empty lists, empty strings.
- just return null. Force the calling code to check the result if it matters. null is type-compatible (your method can remain `public Car mostExpensive()`), the type you receive is transparent (you can just pass your null ref around to other methods, assuming they know how to deal with it), but what can be annoying is that you can't tell at code-writing time if null could happen or not. Fortunately, there is a solution for that: Annotation frameworks. Annotate your method return types, and your method param types, to indicate whether or not they can handle null, and at write time you'll get red wavy underlines where you fail to take null into account. Voila. That's the best of all worlds, and there are various options, most of which have decent IDE support.
- Extra method. `java.util.Map` doesn't just have a `.get(k)` method. It also has a `.getOrDefault(k, defValue)` method: If `k` is not in the map, `defValue` is returned. Otherwise, the mapping is returned. Now the calling code can decide to use the dummy car as response. This is great for generalized utility methods, like map.get
- The bad one: Optional. You don't want this. It is not particularly javalike.

Comment: I agree about `Optional`, it's just a `null` in a wrapper. But there's another option, define your own exception and throw that. That's more like what you'd see in Python, but sometimes it's clearer to throw the special case of "none found" off into a `catch` block away from your main code.